# Couldnt solve with other solutoins - Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v13.27.0.1:

Tags: android, gradle

I tried other SO solutions and with lower and same support lib version but everytime it's giving me this error:
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v13.27.0.0:
Open File

Heres the app.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.github.blackjack"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13.27.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Tried adding maven on
build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
    //        maven{            url 'https://maven.google.com'}
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir

}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: change appcompat version to 27.0.1 and implement the V-13 support dependency in place of compile

Comment: Thanks. Will try and update.

Comment: Same result with both version of appcompat and v-13 - 27.0.1.

Comment: what exactly shows on your gradle error?

Comment: Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v13.27.0.0(according to version): Open File

Comment: is any offline support related error comes?

Comment: no other error shows. only this comes on message window.

Comment: share your error image so that I can identify the actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13.27.0.1'
```

it should be:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'
```

it should be `:` not `.` after `support-v13`